# Using an array find within an array find

Tags: system-verilog

Is there a way to use an array locator function as the condition to an array locator function? Something like the following:

I know I can simply loop through the arrays but I'm hoping for a more concise method

```
module tb;
  typedef struct {
    string name;
    int id;
  } positions_t;

  typedef struct {
    positions_t positions[];
    string unit_name;
  } injector_t;

  injector_t injectors[$] = '{
    '{
      unit_name: "unit1",
      positions: '{
        '{name: "ha", id:0},
        '{name: "he", id:0},
        '{name: "hi", id:0}
      }
    }
  };

  injector_t filtered_injectors[$];

  initial begin
    // LIKE THIS!
    filtered_injectors = injectors.find with (
      item.positions.find with (item.name == "hi")
    );
    $display("filtered list = %p", filtered_injectors);
  end
endmodule
```

Comment: Did you try it? What do you expect it to display?

Comment: Hmm, I thought I was getting a compile error but now it seems to be working. Whoops...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find` returns a queue, so this seems to work

```
filtered_injectors = injectors.find with (
  item.positions.find with (item.name == "hi") != {}
);
```

Comment: Turns out my own code actually works, but your solution documents the intent better. You're missing a tick (') before the empty array, please fix and I'll accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: actually it should not work in your case. `with` expression should be evaluated to a boolean type. I do not think that this is happening in your case.

Comment: I was able to compile and run it on Questa. I'll have to see why it worked. Yes, I agree that it should've been a boolean type.